# Is retrofit using OkHttpClient only?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Is retrofit using OkHttpClient only?

If not set Client.Provider into RestAdapter.Builder.

Answer (score 1):

By default, retrofit(from retrofit 2.0 onwards) is using OkHttpClient. If you want other clients, you can mention while creating the builder. Please note that from retrofit 2.0 onwards '**Retrofit**' is used instead of '**RestAdapter**'.

Comment: Yeah, thnaks. but I'm using 1.9.0 and I checked the cod lines

Comment: Can you be more specific? I couldn't get your actual problem.

Comment: Sorry. Comment has not sended....

It is not a problem, just a concern. I'm using 1.9.0 and I can't make sense.

I find the code lines that instantiate another Client with another cases.

Why provides another Client with another cases, because it contains  OkHttp library inside.

Is it possible that couldn't find the class path at Application create time?